# adb shell top thread info

Tags: android, frameworks

[adb shell top thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpkmP.png)

Please tell me why:

1. The process of com. android. car is the thread information printed out by me after running the adb shell top - H - p $(pidof com. android. car) command;
2. Its main thread is TID=892, with one child thread with TID=1528;
3. I found that the main thread 892 and the sub thread 1528 have the same name, and the package name is com.android.car; I am quite sure that I did not manually create this 1528;

In summary, **please tell me why does Android OS create a thread named 1528 with the same name as the main thread, and its name is still the package name of the app? Secondly, could you please tell me where the code for this setup is located in AOSP?** Thank you very much, big brothers;